# Using cin.get(). for numerous times

Tags: c++, string

I have just started to learn C++.

I've learned that we could use code like

```
char name1[size];
char name2[size];
cin.get(name1,size).get();
cin.get(name2,size).get();
```

and it doesn't make error.

So I understood that function `get()` could be chained more than twice to read inputs.
So I tried to make it like

```
char name1[size];
char name2[size];
cin.get(name1,size).get().get(name2,size).get();
```

but i get an error on `cin.`

> Error E0153 on Visual Studio. "Expression must have class type".

So, could somebody tell me

---

**why does the first code is correct meanwhile second code is wrong?**

---

Comment: you need to explain: "it made an error on cin". Compile time error? Runtime error?

Comment: Error E0153 on Visual Studio. "It needs class format on the statement".

Comment: please show a [mcve] and the error message verbatim. Does it really just say "it needs ...." what is  "it" ?

Comment: please one question per question

Comment: Thanks for giving advice. I fixed what you have said. I'll not make any mistakes again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return values of [`istream::get()` and `istream::get(char&)` differ](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/):

```
int istream::get();
istream& istream::get (char& c);
```

So the overload without an argument returns the value of the read char, while the overload with the argument returns a reference to the same `istream`, which makes chaining possible.

Comment: Oh I got it. It really helped me. Thanks for your concise and good solution.